# lsp failing while requiring uninstalled packages

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp, java

I have (I think) installed `lsp` and `lsp-java`.  My java mode hook starts with

```
  (message "Running my-java-mode-hook")
  (auto-revert-mode)

  ;; Set up lsp
  (require 'lsp-mode)
  (require 'lsp-java)
  (lsp)
  (require 'dap-mode)
  (dap-mode)
  (require 'company-mode)
  (company-mode)
```

When I try to do completion with company mode, it seems to just offer strings from elsewhere in the buffer, not just valid methods if I have typed something like `client.get`.  Suspecting that `lsp` might not have initialized correctly, I tried running `M-x lsp`.

That failed with

```
require: Symbol’s value as variable is void: lsp-actionscript
```

It is true that I do not have `lsp-actionscript` installed, but I do not use action script.  Looking at the code, it appears that it is calling `(require package nil t)` (where package is `'lsp-actionscript` but throwing an error despite the `t` argument.

Is there something I need to be doing?

Experimenting a bit, I find that the lines return nil:

```
(require 'foo-bar nil t)
(require 'lsp-actionscrip nil t)
```

but

```
(require 'lsp-actionscript nil t)
```

throws an error when I evaluate them in the scratch buffer.  (Note that "action script" that just returns nil is missing a t.). Is there some reason why `lsp-actionscript` should be special to require?

*Edit (more details):*

I deleted and re-installed all of my packages.
With the debugger, I have seen that it does find `lsp-actionscript` and starts to load it.

It appears to fail at the end at

```
(lsp-consistency-check lsp-actionscript)
```

where it does not find the argument variable.

*Attempted workaround*

I customized `lsp-auto-configure` to `nil`, since I don't need any of those packages.

It then got passed that step and failed because `-andfn` was not defined.  That appears to be a `dash` function.  I have "dash-20200119.2310" installed from <strike>elpa</strike>Melpa.  However, it seems that `-andfn` is defined in `dash-functional`.

I am getting both dash* and lsp-* from <strike>elpa</strike>Melpa, so I would think they would be consistent.

Adding `(require 'dash-functional)` before calling `(lsp)` fixed those errors, but I still do not get the correct completion list, so something else must be going on.

Any ideas what is causing my problems?

**Emacs version**:

GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, NS appkit-2022.60 Version 11.6.4 (Build 20G417))
of 2022-03-02

Comment: If you've installed lsp-mode, then lsp-actionscript ships with it: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/blob/master/clients/lsp-actionscript.el. So (require 'lsp-actionscript) should not error.  I'd probably try reinstalling lsp-mode?

Comment: dash-functional is deprecated (see https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/2615#issuecomment-782681301 for a similar discussion), since your dash version appears to be from 2020, I'd try updating it (making sure to M-x package-refresh-contents before hand)

Comment: And probably lsp-mode as well if you didn't run M-x package-refresh-contents before reinstalling it

Comment: I didn't run `package-refresh-contents`, but I have restarted emacs multiple times since I started this process.  I'm guessing that's equivalent (for these purposes)

Comment: Unless you explicitly `(package-refresh-contents)` in your init the package list won't be refreshed - I haven't seen your init file but if you have something like `(when (not package-archive-contents) (package-refresh-contents))` this will only run it if there is no package list already